# Dataframe consisting of mixed class, how to convert that into numerical in R

Tags: r, data-modeling

Tried this code **sapply(df,function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))**, gives an error and is removing all the observation

Comment: It may be better to inspect the original file and figure out why R has converted some columns to character. Then you can fix the issue when the file is read into R using, for example, the `colClasses` to `read.csv` or `col_types` for `readr::read_csv`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
df[] <- lapply(df , as.numeric)
```